# Error when Inserting CSV file values into a postgreSQL using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, csv, psycopg2, python-3.5

```js
#!/usr/bin/python3.5


import psycopg2, csv

#create a connection object
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='testdb' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='password'")

#use cursor object to execute commands 
cur= conn.cursor()

reader = csv.reader(open('E:\\data\\sample.csv', 'r'))

for row in reader:
    print (row[1])
    
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO "data" ("VehicleNo", "DepartureDate", "DepartureCity", "SeatNumber", "UCI", "PAXSurname", "FirstName", "PNRNumber", "Ticket", "FQTVNumber", "PassportNo", "PassportExpDate")' +
                'VALUES %s', [(val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11,val12)])
    
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
```

```html
Sample.csv
VehicleNo,DepartureDate,DepartureCity,SeatNumber,UCI,PAXSurname,FirstName,PNRNumber,Ticket,FQTVNumber,PassportNo,PassportExpDate
100,2010-11-25,ATB,,1087100000858D99,RAMAN,CHETTI,6WIL66,6034202799543,,KP4523,20201220
230,2011-10-28,KLI,025G,001035477423095B,MEHMOOD,HIDDY,63IC4Y,6035448301629,,YL0152441,20190609
270,2012-10-13,KWI,002K,20632703000E3281,ALMARRI,GALI,2UITWH,6039659907963,,K302216,20161020
502,2015-12-03,ADB,026B,200235B3000C4633,HONGI,XYIUE,4S63HA,6035853329241,,DL0007453,20171020
```

I'm newbie, & I'm using python 3.5 I want to insert the data in a CSV file into a PostgreSQL table using psycopg2.

Traceback (most recent call last): File "E:\Shared Folder Home\Python\Python3\postgressqlCSV.py", line 23, in 'VALUES %s', [(val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11,val12)]) NameError: name 'val1' is not defined

I'm getting above error when I used the python code shown below

Can someone help me to solve this issue. I have inserted a sample of my CSV file. Thanks you very much for your time & effort.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear. You do not define `val1`. Turn the list of strings in each row into a tuple. Use the Psycopg2's `execute` method parameter passing. You do not want the first headers row.

for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    print (i,row)
    if i == 0: continue

```
cursor.execute('''
    INSERT INTO data (
        VehicleNo, DepartureDate, DepartureCity, SeatNumber, UCI,
        PAXSurname, FirstName, PNRNumber, Ticket, FQTVNumber,
        PassportNo, PassportExpDate
    ) values %s''', [tuple(row)]
)
```

BTW double quoting identifiers is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, now i'm getting an error stating; Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Shared Folder Home\Python\Python3\postgressqlCSV.py", line 25, in <module>
    ) values %s''', [tuple(row)]
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "data" does not exist
LINE 2:         INSERT INTO "data" (
                            ^                          So I inserted a statement to create "data" table as follows;
cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data''')

Comment: cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE data
        (ID INT PRIMARY KEY        NOT NULL,
        VehicleNo   INT       NOT NULL,
        DepartureDate  CHAR(50)   ,
        DepartureCity CHAR(50)   ,
        SeatNumber  CHAR(50)  ,
        UCI   CHAR(50) ,
        PAXSurname  CHAR(50)  ,
        FirstName   CHAR(50) ,
        PNRNumber   CHAR(50) ,
        Ticket   INT ,
        FQTVNumber   CHAR(50) ,
        PassportNo  CHAR(50)  ,
        PassportExpDate CHAR(50)
        );''')
print ("Table data created successfully")

Comment: The error msg is; Table data created successfully 0 ['100','2010-11-25','ATB','','1087100000858D99','RAMAN','CHE‌​TTI','6WIL66','60342‌​02799543','','KP4523‌​,20201220'] 1 ['230','2011-10-28','KLI','025G','001035477423095B','MEHMOOD‌​','HIDDY','63IC4Y','‌​6035448301629','','Y‌​L0152441','20190609'‌​] Traceback (most recent call last): File "E:\Shared Folder Home\Python\Python3\postgressqlCSV.py", line 49, in <module> ) values %s''', [tuple(row)] psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "VehicleNo" of relation "data" does not exist LINE 3: "VehicleNo", "DepartureDate", "DepartureCity"...

Comment: @Klllmmm Remove the double quotes.